# App Script - Alternative to using UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Good afternoon

Trying to access API

https://developer-portal.driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/apis/vehicle-enquiry-service/code-examples.html#ves-api-code-examples

from App Script

Have accessed other API's in the past & used UrlFetchApp, but does not seem to be supported by this API

Not sure how to use one of the other options

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From [your provided official document](https://developer-portal.driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/apis/vehicle-enquiry-service/code-examples.html#ves-api-code-examples), you want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script.

  ```bash
  curl --location --request POST 'https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles' \
  --header 'x-api-key: REPLACE WITH YOUR API KEY' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"registrationNumber": "AA19AAA"}'
  ```
- You have already confirmed that the above curl command worked fine.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const url = "https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles";
  const data = { "registrationNumber": "AA19AAA" };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: { "x-api-key": "REPLACE WITH YOUR API KEY" },
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
  console.log(res.getContentText());
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample, it supposes that you have already confirmed that the sample curl command works fine with your values. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)